# XPath: grouping Boolean Operators

Tags: csv, xpath, xpath-2.0

In the context of XPath 2.0, I'm trying to import a CSV file, yet though I feel the intention of my XPath filter is clear, I want to verify that the following is syntactically correct:

```
/node[image[1][string()] and ( (rocklea[1] + sydney[1]) > 0) and (productgroupcode[1] = "SYS" or productgroupcode[1] = "SVR" or productgroupcode[1] = "NBK" or productgroupcode[1] = "NAS")]
```

Can my Stack Overflow friends please check the code for correct implementation?

Essentially, the XPath filter must stipulate that:

1. the `image[1]` element must not be empty
2. The sum of elements `rocklea[1]` and `sydney[1]` must be greater than zero
3. Element `productgroupcode[1]` must be equal to one of the following values: "SYS", "SVR", "NBK" or "NAS"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is syntactically correct. From your description of the criteria, the XPath appears to be correct (it would be easier to know for sure if you provided sample data to validate against).

There are a few unnecessary parenthesis that could be removed, and since you have tagged it as XPath 2.0, you could shorten it a bit by evaluating the `productgroupcode[1]` value against a sequence of values:

```
/node[
  image[1][string()] and 
  (rocklea[1] + sydney[1]) > 0 and 
  productgroupcode[1] = ("SYS", "SVR", "NBK", "NAS") 
]
```